# Parsing JSON in Golang for drawing polygons

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm parsing a large JSON file in Go where I need to take only specific items from the JSON.

It's usually a very large file, but eventually, it becomes this:

```
"textAnnotations": [
    {
        "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
                {
                    "x": 136,
                    "y": 119
                },
                {
                    "x": 5606,
                    "y": 119
                },
                {
                    "x": 5606,
                    "y": 3985
                },
                {
                    "x": 136,
                    "y": 3985
                }
            ]
        },
        "description": "Description",
        "locale": "en"
    },
    {
        "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
                {
                    "x": 3420,
                    "y": 122
                },
                {
                    "x": 3439,
                    "y": 122
                },
                {
                    "x": 3439,
                    "y": 144
                },
                {
                    "x": 3420,
                    "y": 144
                }
            ]
        },
        "description": "10"
    },
    {
        "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
                {
                    "x": 4106,
                    "y": 119
                },
                {
                    "x": 4128,
                    "y": 119
                },
                {
                    "x": 4128,
                    "y": 141
                },
                {
                    "x": 4106,
                    "y": 141
                }
            ]
        },
        "description": "12"
    },
```

I need to take the vertices and description of all of the "boundingPoly"'s in that are within "textAnnotations". I've looked at a few JSON parsing libraries but none seem to do exactly what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need your go structure laid out correctly.

Something like this:

```
type YourType struct {
    TextAnnotations []struct {
        BoundingPoly struct {
            Vertices []struct {
                X int `json:"x"`
                Y int `json:"y"`
            } `json:"vertices"`
        } `json:"boundingPoly"`
        Description string `json:"description"`
        Locale      string `json:"locale,omitempty"`
    } `json:"textAnnotations"`
}
```

The rest is pretty straight forward: https://play.golang.org/p/ICtREyQyjF

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-generate a Go struct from a JSON example using this tool: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

I'm using it every time I need to create a struct for a complex JSON object.